# CSS Pointer Events – Accept Drag, Reject Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, pointer-events

**tldr; I need an element to register drag and drop pointer events, but pass click and other pointer events to elements behind it.**

I am building a drag and drop photo upload feature in react using [`react-dropzone`](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/). I want the `dropzone` to be over the whole page, so if you drag a file onto any part of the page, you can drop it to upload the image. The `dropzone` is transparent when no file is dragged over it, so I need clicks to register with elements behind it.

To accomplish this, I gave the dropzone component the following style:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
pointer-events: none;
```

However, `pointer-events: none;` causes the `dropzone` to not recognize the necessary drag and drop events. Is there any way to recognize these specific pointer events, while passing others (like click) to elements behind the `dropzone`?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `draggable` attribute. It worked for me

```
<p draggable="true">
  jkjfj
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED ANSWER:

```css
#dropzone{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10; //set this to make it sit on the top of everything
    pointer-events: none;
}

.user-is-dragging #dropzone{
    pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

```js
//element declarations
const dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
const body = document.body;

//timeout function to help detect when the user is dragging something
let dragHandle;

// utility function to detect drag & drop support
function dragDropSupported() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    return ('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div);
}

function initDragDrop(){

    //simply exit / do other stuff if drag & drop is not supported
    if(!dragDropSupported()){
        console.warn("Drag & drop not supported");
        return;
    }

    //add user-is-dragging class which enables pointer events for the drop event
    body.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
        body.classList.add("user-is-dragging");
        clearTimeout(dragHandle);
        dragHandle = setTimeout(() => {
            body.classList.remove("user-is-dragging");
        }, 200);
    });

    //this is to prevent the browser from opening the dragged file(s)
    dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    dropzone.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
        //prevent the browser from opening the dragged file(s)
        e.preventDefault();

        //dragged files
        const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        console.log(files);
    })

}
```

Comment: Where does the variable 'drag Drop Support' and 'dragDropTarget' reference?

Comment: This function is missing many previous declarations such as: timeout ["dragLeaveBodyRemoveclass"], body, dragDropSupport, etc .. If it is executed it gives many errors, it would be good to put it in a cleaner way

Comment: I was young when i wrote this answer, thanks for commenting i am editing it soon so it provides a proper & clean solution and in vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue and managed to solve it by, setting z-index for dropzone to 1, while setting z-index for say  elements to 2, with position relative.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by setting pointer-events to be none on .file-drop but auto on .file-drop > .file-drop-target.file-drop-dragging-over-frame

Comment: you have a simple and real example to be able to see it, because it doesn't work for me with pointer-event in css, I can't get it to work