# Trigger dragenter on a container, not children

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML, basically a div container having 100% of its surface covered with a header and a body.:

```html
<div class="ui-layout--col">
  <div class="ui-layout--cell-container"> <!-- $0 -->
    <div class="ui-layout--panel-header-bar" draggable="true">
      <label>New panel</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout--panel-body">
      body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to listen to the `dragenter` and `dragleave` events on the container div, and apply a style to it when dragging over. The problem is, as I do this:

```js
        $0.ondragenter = e => {
            console.log('enter', e.currentTarget, e.target)
            // e.target.style.opacity = '50%'
        }
```

It becomes evident that the event triggers on the container's children (the header and the body), and not the container. So the event triggers multiple times within the same container, which causes issues.

Is there a way to listen to events only on the container and none of it's children, even if the container is completely covered by the children?

How would you tackle this issue?

Thank you

Comment: why not just apply the style change to `e.currentTarget`, or any other reference you have to the actual container div?

Comment: @RobinZigmond because when we dragleave the area, I remove the styling effect. dragleave also triggers multiple times within the same container, resulting in flickering or outright not working because removing the style was done after applying it. Imho, the clean solution would be to have the event trigger only once on enter and leave

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use css [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

E.g. something like:

```
.children {pointer-events: none;}

#container {pointer-events: auto;}
```

---

Also, this might be useful:

[CSS Pointer Events – Accept Drag, Reject Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527246/css-pointer-events-accept-drag-reject-click)